# How to get the length of piped array in template?

Tags: angular

sample code:
if not using pipe, I can get array length by:

```
<my-component [arrLen]='arrayA.length'></my-component>
```

But what if I want to get the length of a filtered array by a pipe? (Below not working)

```
<my-component [arrLen]='arrayA | arrayFilterPipe:filterParam'></my-component>
```

How to do this? Thanks

Comment: Did you try `[arrLen]='(arrayA | arrayFilterPipe:filterParam).length'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your code

```
<my-component [arrLen]='arrayA | arrayFilterPipe:filterParam'></my-component>
```

To

```
<my-component [arrLen]='(arrayA | arrayFilterPipe:filterParam).length'></my-component>
```